# Debugging HTTP client in eclipse

Tags: java

I am trying to debug small HTTP client checking for its headers . It Is hard for me to check the header of HTTP ,is there any eclipse plugin available for monitoring HTTP client (HTTP headers)

Comment: Are you looking to run the servlet in debug mode, or are you looking to examine the HTTP request headers?

Comment: I am looking to examine http request header

Comment: try out this http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-monitor-http-communication-in-eclipse.html?page=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the blow link. There is a tool in eclipse name `TCP/IP monitor`.It provides a console.
All you have to add is you server port lets assume `localhost:8080` and a monitoring port `8081` (according to reference )

then when you will call on `http://localhost:8081/your_servlet_or_page/...`
the call will be redirect to `http://localhost:8080/your_servlet_or_page/...`
and you will be able to see headers in console `TCP/IP monitor console`

reference # 
http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-monitor-http-communication-in-eclipse.html
http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.wst.wsi.ui.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftmonitor.html

The above reference is tested by me..it is working fine.

Comment: Could have been a useful answer if you actually linked somewhere instead of back to the same question.

Comment: "You can monitor the TCP/IP activity using the TCP/IP Monitor view (Window > Show View > Other > Debug > TCP/IP Monitor)." http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.wst.server.ui.doc.user%2Ftopics%2Frwtcpvw.html

Answer (score 0):

Check if this helps

```
public class GetHttpHeaders {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            try {
                URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080");
                URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

                for (int i = 0;; i++) {
                    String name = conn.getHeaderFieldKey(i);
                    String value = conn.getHeaderField(i);
                    if (name == null && value == null) {
                        break;
                    }
                    if (name == null) {
                        System.out
                                .println("Server HTTP version, Response code:");
                        System.out.println(value);
                        System.out.print("\n");
                    } else {
                        System.out.println(name + "=" + value);
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }
```